# How do you compare a string containing an angle bracket '<' in bash?

Tags: bash

The following bash script is giving me problems:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ $VAR -eq "<EMPTY>" ]]; then echo "Hello World!"; fi
```

Bash fails, complaining:

```
line 3: [[: <EMPTY>: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "<EMPTY>")
```

How can I test if the string contained in `VAR` is equivalent to the string `"<EMPTY>"`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using the wrong operator. `==` is for strings, `-eq` is for numbers.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ $VAR == "<EMPTY>" ]]; then echo "Hello World!"; fi
```

Comment: In `[[`, you do not have to quote a non-existent VAR.

Answer (score 2):

Inside `[[ ... ]]`, `-eq` has a different meaning: it is used to compare integers. You can use `(( ... ))` to compare integeres with normal operators, though. Use the following for strings:

```
[[ $VAR == "<EMPTY>" ]]
```

Comment: `-eq` still has meaning inside `[[ ... ]]`. It means "return true if arg1 is equal to arg2," according to the bash man page. Its operands must be integers.