# Comparision in shell script

Tags: shell, unix, comparison, sh, comparison-operators

I am doing comparision in shell script

```
              if [ $# -lt 10  ]
              then
              echo "PROCEED"
              else 
              echo "STOP"
```

I run the script as ./test.sh 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11
then output is "STOP"
Instead of using "-lt" if I use "<"

```
              if [ $# < 10  ]
              then
              echo "PROCEED"
              else 
              echo "STOP"
```

then output is "PROCEED".

My question is in case of shell script if I compare the no greater than 10 cause this problem.
Please guide me on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As seen in [Advanced Bash Shell Scripting Guide - 7.3. Other Comparison Operators](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/advanced_bash_scripting_guide/comparison-ops.html):

> **string comparison**
>
> <
>
> is less than, in ASCII alphabetical order
>
> if [[ "$a" < "$b" ]]
>
> if [ "$a" \< "$b" ]
>
> Note that the "<" needs to be escaped within a [ ] construct.

So the way to do it is with `-lt` or, quoting again:

> **integer comparison**
>
> **-lt** is less than
>
> if [ "$a" -lt "$b" ]
>
> **<** is less than (within double parentheses)
>
> (("$a" < "$b"))

Comment: If I use if [ "$a" \< "$b" ] then it should work is that you are suggesting.

Comment: No, it just works for string comparisons. It might get a good output, but just based on ASCII. What I mean is that you have to use `lt`.

Comment: I use "(" bracket instead of "[" this one . if (( $# < 10)) and problem solved

Comment: Great! I will update my post reflecting that, as it is always indicated in the link I provided.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use < rather than -lt when comparing numbers, since -lt does STRING comparisons.

Comment: if i use "<" then output should be STOP but output is "PROCEED"

Answer (score 0):

Please be aware, Bash uses the buildin "test" implementation , man test -> [link](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?test)

This is also eplained here -> [Stackoverflow Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12183181/how-do-you-compare-a-string-containing-an-angle-bracket-in-bash)

The angle brackets are commonly used for command redirections! [link](http://codeidol.com/unix/suse/Cool-Shell-Tricks/Piping-and-Directing-Output/)

If you are comparing integers use -lt for lower than.